# How do I mock %x in a test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, tdd

I've got something like this :

```
class Something
  def some_method
    %x{xyz}
  end
end
```

And in the spec :

```
describe Something do
  describe "#some_method" do
    it "should execute xyz command in a subshell" do
      x = Something.new
      #What should come here?
      x.some_method
    end
  end
end
```

I know how I can mock "system" . But my question is specific to "%x" . So how to mock %x ?

Comment: @theTinMan , nothing. I'm not doing anything with the return value in this case .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you are looking for is

```
x.should_receive(:`).once.with('xyz')
```

the backticks are actually a method being called and whatever is put between them is passed as a String argument. `%x{...}` is just a syntax variation to the backticks and thus cause the same method invocation.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `%x{xyz}` this is equivalent to `` `xyz` `` which turns out to be syntax sugar for calling a method on Kernel called `` ` `` (the method name is literally a single backtick character) with the string argument "xyz".

Because Ruby syntax doesn't let you define a method of this name you need to use `define_method` instead of `def` like so:

```
module Kernel
  define_method(:"`") do |x|
    x + "blah"
  end
end
```

And now `` `xyz` `` and `%x{xyz}` call this new method:

```
%x{xyz} #=> "xyzblah"
`foobar` #=> "foobarblah"
```

Comment: Scott Olson - Thanks for explaining that. So your suggestion is to replace %x with \`, and use ``x.should_receive(:`).with('xyz')`` , right ? I tried that. Is there no way to mock %x ? I was just curious about this one :)

Comment: This is interesting - I thought the behavior of `%x{xyz}` was hard-wired!

Comment: You don't need to replace `%x` with \`, it's just that they are two different syntaxes for the exact same thing in Ruby. (They both call Kernel#\`)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Scott Olson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1535283/scott-olson)'s comment, since `%x` is just `` Kernel#` ``, this works for me:

```
  x = Something.new
  expect(x).to receive(:`).with(xyz)
  x.some_method
```